# Запятая или двоеточие в БСП?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, бсп, двоеточие

Запятую или двоеточие нужно ставить?

"Как я и говорил() зарплату выдадут только через неделю"

"Я же сказала() купи хлеб"

"Я же говорил тебе() не нужно туда соваться"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Как я и говорил, зарплату выдадут только через неделю". Вводное предложение.

"Я же сказала: купи хлеб". БСП, значение изъяснения. Можно не двоеточие, а тире.

"Я же говорил тебе: не нужно туда соваться". БСП, значение изъяснения.

Comment: Извините, а что значит БСП?

Comment: БСП - бесоюзное сложное предложение

Answer (score 2):

***Это бесоюзное сложное предложение***. Возможно и тире и двоеточие. 
 Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если она (нередко — неполное предложение) имеет изъяснительное значение (перед ней можно вставить союз что), причем в первой части не содержится интонационного предупреждения о последующем изложении какого-либо факта: Ср.: Овца же говорит — она всю ночь спала (Кр.);

См. Справочник-практикум. Розенталь. Д. Э. [Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151)